# How can types be derived impilictly in FlatMapFunction in Apache Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

How can the types be implicitly specified when you are using FlatMapFunction class in Scala?

```
val test = env.fromElements((0,1111),(1,2222))

test.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction[A,B]() { 
      override def flatMap(implicit  x:A,  out:Collector[B]):Unit = {
        x => x match {
          case (k,v) =>
            if (moveToP(v))
              out.write(v)
        }
      }
    })
```

Error:  trait FlatMapFunction takes type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are you asking for, but will try to answer anyway ;) .

You can't instantiate an object with generic types. As you stream is of type `DataStream[(Int, Int)]` you need to apply a `new FlatMapFunction[(Int, Int), Int]`.

In scala you can use a lambda expression for flatMap:

```
test.flatMap((x, out: Collector[Int]) => {
  x match {
    case (k,v) =>
      if (moveToP(v))
        out.collect(v)
  }
}).print()
```

or without the collector:

```
test.flatMap(x => {
  if (moveToP(x._2)) List(x._2) else List.empty
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me. I didn't tumble to the second idea without the collector. The first example needs an explicit specification of the collector type and if it is a complex thing then it makes things much harder.